# Postman pre-request script login with Query Params

Tags: postman-pre-request-script

I want to create a pre-script in postman to login so that i can get tokens.

```js
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://localhost/api/login',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
    body: {
      mode: 'formdata',
      formdata: [
        {key: "email", value: "myemail@mydoman.com", disabled: false, description: {content:"", type:"text/plain"}},
        {key: "password", value: "mypass", disabled: false, description: {content:"", type:"text/plain"}},
        {key: "action", value: "login", disabled: false, description: {content:"", type:"text/plain"}}
      ]
    }
  }, function(err, response) { 
       pm.environment.set("access_token");
  });
```

I'm still no get token with those pre-script, help needed

Answer (score 1):

```
const loginRequest = {
    url: pm.environment.get('my_url') +"/api/login",
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'Content-Type: application/json',
    body: {
        mode: 'application/json',
        raw: JSON.stringify({        
            "email": "myemail@mydoman.com",
            "password":"mypass"
        })
    }
};
pm.sendRequest(loginRequest, function (err, response) {
    pm.environment.set("access_token", response.json().token);
});
```

[image]

[image]